# How to use @Transactional with @KafkaListener?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

Is there any possibility to use declarative tx management (via @Transactional) with @KafkaListener annotated method ?
I would like to use it in order to, for example, define separate tx timeout per listener.
My setup is as follows:

TransactionManager:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(value = {HibernateTransactionManager.class})
public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> chainedHibernateTm(KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> kafkaTransactionManager,
                                                                                 org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager) {
  return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(
    kafkaTransactionManager, 
    hibernateTransactionManager);
}
```

KafkaListener:

```
@KafkaListener(topic = "my_topic")
@Transactional(timeout = 5)
public void handleMessage(SomeMessage message){
}
```

The problem is - KafkaMessageListenerContainer creates it's own transaction before such method is invoked - it uses its own TransactionTemplate:

```
@Nullable
private TransactionTemplate determineTransactionTemplate() {
  return this.transactionManager != null
    ? new TransactionTemplate(this.transactionManager)
    : null;
}
```

TransactionInterceptor is not used. So how to set specific tx timeout for concrete @KafkaListener method ?

Answer (score 3):

The aspects of transaction management through plain `@Transactional` don't work with Kafka listeners as you intent - there is no in-built interaction.

There is a dedicated chapter how to use application events with within a transaction: [Transaction Bound Event](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-event) using the annotation [`@TransactionalEventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html) helps to assure that the transaction has completed successfully.

> You can register a regular event listener by using the @EventListener annotation. If you need to bind it to the transaction, use @TransactionalEventListener. When you do so, the listener is bound to the commit phase of the transaction by default.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but it's a bit complicated because you have to send the consumed offset(s) to the Kafka transaction.

Instead of using a `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager`, you can use a `KafkaTransactionManager` for the container and `@Transactional` for the `HibernateTransactionManager`.

This will give similar results, since the hibernate TX will commit just before the Kafka transaction (and if the hibernate commit fails, the Kafka TX will roll back).

**EDIT**

To configure a different chained TM into each listener container you can do something like this.

```java
@Component
class ContainerFactoryCustomizer {

    ContainerFactoryCustomizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory,
            ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> chainedOne,
            ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> chainedTwo) {
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(
                container -> {
                    String groupId = container.getContainerProperties().getGroupId();
                    if (groupId.equals("foo")) {
                        container.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedOne);
                    }
                    else {
                        container.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedTwo);
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Where each chained TM has a Hibernate TM with a different default timeout.

The `groupid` is populated from the `@KafkaListener` `id` or `groupId` property.

Comment: Garry Russell. Thanks. But, could You give any more detailed suggestions how to implement custom tx timeout per KafkaListener? I still want synchronization with hibernate tx manager. You said this can be done, but I do not know how.

Comment: While Hibernate has a notion of transaction timeout, there is no concept of a timeout in the Kafka transactions. The simplest solution is to have the container manage just the Kafka transaction and use `@Transactional` for the Hibernate TM; the results will be similar to transaction synchronization. To use a chained TM in the container, you could configure each container to use a different chained TM, wherein the Hibernate TMs are configured with different default timeouts. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanations. If I choose the first option (without chained tm) would I have to manually send consumed offsets to kafka transaction? This option looks interesting because I could use @Transactional to configure hib. tm. Currently (with chained tm) this annotation is totally ignored. I also considered customizing KafkaListenerContainerManager, but I would have to rewrite it totally, because TransactionTemplate used there to start transaction is final and cannot be modified :)

Comment: `>If I choose the first option (without chained tm) would I have to manually send consumed offsets to kafka transaction? `. No; the container is oblivious to the DB tx and will send the offsets (if the DB TX commits). If the DB commit fails, the Kafka TX will roll back (and the after rollback processor will re-seek the partitions). The annotation is not "totally ignored", the default propagation is `REQUIRED` and the interceptor sees there is an existing transaction so no need to start another one. Sending the offsets yourself would only be required if the container was not transactional.

Comment: Gary Russell - I have checked and the first option (without chained tm) works  - if hibernate transaction timeouts, kafka transaction is rolled back. But now I have similar problem on the producer side - method annotated with @Transactional with timeout - inside this method I try to send kafka message using KafkaTemplate. Hibernate transaction timeouts properly, but KafkaTemplate used inside this method sends message to the topic. My expectation is that it shouldn't. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Update: It works, the problem was that I was reading sent messages in console consumer with isolation-level=read_committed. But is it ok that @Transactional uses Hibernate TM od the producer side instead of ChainedTM ? It seems to work properly.

Comment: Yes; see my comment on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/869#issuecomment-604682229). The template synchronizes the kafka transaction with the existing Hibernate transaction and it is committed after the Hibernate transaction.

Comment: Thanks. I used console consumer with isolation-level=read_uncommited so I thought It does not work. If I understand it correctly, I have two options: simply do not use ChainedTM at all or use ChainedTM(kafkaTM, hibernateTM) - in this order, so that kafkaTM rollback / commit after hibernate transaction ?

Comment: Correct; but for producer-only transactions it's simpler to just use transaction synchronization.

Comment: Hmm, It seems to me that I do not need ChainedTM at all - on both consumer and producer side. I only need to remember to start hibernate transaction (f.ex. using @Transactional on consumer side) because without ChainedTM it will no longer be started automatically...